# What's the standard notation for summing over all subsets of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, summation, notation

I'm reading this book on [interpretable AI](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/decomposition.html). In section 8.4 the author uses the following notation for a summation across all subsets of a set:

$$ \sum_{S \subseteq \{1, \dots, p\}} \hat f_S(x_S) $$

Is this standard notation? Wouldn't it better to explicitly state:

$$ \sum_{S \in P(\{1, \dots, p\})} \hat f_S(x_S) $$

where $P(\dots)$ represents the powerset of whatever's contained within the parentheses. Are these two equivalent, and which one is considered clearest?

Comment: the first is usually understandable (and what I would use in practice after explaining the notation once). The second is fine if you’ve already introduced the notation $P(\cdots)$ for the power set. In any case, clearest is to explain what you mean once, and then stay consistent.

Comment: Okay, are these the only two forms of notation that get used? Would you say the first is the one that's used in general?

Comment: I think so. The first also has fewer symbols to type, so that’s an extra benefit (also, maybe conceptually, it may take people (well me atleast) that extra 0.001s to wrap their brains around being an element of a more ‘complicated’ space). But whatever, like I said, just pick one, and stick with it. And if this isn’t a commonly occuring notion in a paper, then you can just say in words “$\sum \hat{f}_S(x_S)$, where the sum is taken over all subsets $S$ of $\{1,\dots, p\}$”.

Comment: I've always used the first because it's cleaner to read and comprehend.

Comment: The "$\in$" isn't part of the sum notation. The idea in general is that you sum over all assignments of values to new variables (i.e. variables that appear below the $\sum$ but were not previously introduced) that satisfy the conditions given. So $\sum_{S\subseteq A}$ means sum over all values of $S$ that satisfy $S\subseteq A$ (assuming $A$ is an expression with no new variables).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that $P$ (as opposed to $\mathbb P$ or $\mathbf P$ or $\wp$ or $2^{X}$ or $\operatorname{Pow}$) has been established for the powerset, then "$S\in P(X)$" is logically equivalent to "$S\subseteq X$".

Relatedly, I would say that the two summation notations are equivalent, and neither is more "explicitly stated" than the other.

If $P(X)$ were used a lot in the context around the summation, I might prefer to use $P(X)$ in the summation notation, for familiarity. But because power set notations vary, and because
"subset" is more commonly encountered than "power set", I'd prefer the book's summation notation with $\subseteq$ in most contexts.

Answer (score 9):

I think the first notation is clearly better; subset notation $\subseteq$ is unambiguous and widely understood (it only has this one meaning and no others), and it avoids referring to the powerset.

Notation for the powerset, on the other hand, is not standard, not very commonly used, and collides slightly with other notation (e.g. $P$ is also used to refer to probabilities, or polynomials). If anything I would argue that the use of subset notation is more explicit than the reference to the powerset because it does not require that the reader know that $P$ refers to the powerset as opposed to something else.